# Chess Diagrams with text at LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, chess, chessboard, xskak

I need your help in LaTeX editing:

I want to prepare chess book with tactics. However, I cannot adjust my pages for including text below diagrams. How can I do it?  Here the pictures of my idea (edited .jpeg), and my code.

Now:

[image]
[image]

I want like this:
[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}
\newcounter{diagrams}
\newcommand\printdiagrams{\refstepcounter{diagrams}\thediagrams}
\begin{document}

\part{Positions}
\chapter{a Deflection and overloading}
\printdiagrams
\chessboard[setfen=6k1/4p3/3p2p1/4brp1/7q/1P2B2P/PP1Q2P1/5RK1 b, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.3ex, moverlift=-1.5ex]\hfill\printdiagrams
\chessboard[setfen=Bn3rk1/p4p1p/b2P2p1/2p1b1B1/3q4/8/P4RPP/2RQ2K1 b, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.3ex, moverlift=-1.5ex]\hfill\printdiagrams
\chessboard[setfen=8/1P6/2n1k3/8/3B1p1p/5P1p/8/5K2 w, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.5ex, moverlift=16.5ex]\hfill\printdiagrams
\chessboard[setfen=6k1/1p1b4/3p4/3Pp3/2Q1P1P1/8/3rBq1R/7K b, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.3ex, moverlift=-1.5ex]\hfill\printdiagrams
\chessboard[setfen=4r3/PB6/1n6/8/5k2/1P3pp1/2R5/5K2 w, showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.5ex, moverlift=16.5ex]\hfill

...

\end{document}
```

With regards, Ulvi Bajarani

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}
\newcounter{diagrams}
\newcommand\printdiagrams{\refstepcounter{diagrams}\thediagrams}
\setchessboard{showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.3ex, moverlift=-1.5ex}
\newcommand\tacticboard[2][]{%
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \centering\printdiagrams\chessboard[#2]\par
   \Large\bfseries #1\strut
    \end{minipage}\hfill\ignorespaces }
\begin{document}

\part{Positions}
\chapter{a Deflection and overloading}
\tacticboard[Find a tactic]{setfen=6k1/4p3/3p2p1/4brp1/7q/1P2B2P/PP1Q2P1/5RK1 b}
\tacticboard[is a move relevant?]{setfen=Bn3rk1/p4p1p/b2P2p1/2p1b1B1/3q4/8/P4RPP/2RQ2K1 b}
 \tacticboard{setfen=8/1P6/2n1k3/8/3B1p1p/5P1p/8/5K2 w,moverlift=16.5ex}
\tacticboard[find a draw]{setfen=6k1/1p1b4/3p4/3Pp3/2Q1P1P1/8/3rBq1R/7K b}
\tacticboard{setfen=4r3/PB6/1n6/8/5k2/1P3pp1/2R5/5K2 w,moverlift=16.5ex} 
...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for an answer! But I've a mistake during the compilation:

! File ended while scanning use of \\tacticboard.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> "./Book Start.tex"
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
! Emergency stop.
<*> "./Book Start.tex"
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

Also, I need different formats for both colors (You can see above)

Comment: my code compiles, and I can't know what you did wrong when using it. Regarding the mover: you can naturally move the setting back to the argument.

Comment: The problem was in "[" and "]" symbols, which didn't gave to compile.

Comment: Regarding the mover I've tried, but could not be able to create new command which takes \setchessboard{showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.5ex, moverlift=16.5ex} for white to move. How can I write two separate commands (tacticboardwhite and tacticboardblack)?

Comment: Don't ask follow up questions in comments, I'm the only one getting pinged in such cases. Ask new a question. I correct the mover in my code.