# Align Chess Diagram and notation

Tags: tables, macros, align, chess, xskak

I'm trying to combine both a notation below diagram, but I cannot align them properly. Here, I have [asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496670/chess-diagrams-with-text-at-latex) the question, but I don't want the text be a part of diagram. How could I do (the command is /introductionboard)?

```
\documentclass[paper=8.27in:11.69in]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[total={8.27in,11.69in}, top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.375in, right=0.375in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{texmate}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\addtokomafont{section}{\centering}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newcounter{diagrams}
\newcommand\printdiagrams{\refstepcounter{diagrams}\thediagrams}
\setboardfontfamily{merida}
\setchessboard{showmover=true, moverstyle=triangle, movershift=-1.3ex, moverlift=-1.5ex}
\newcommand\tacticboard[2][]{%
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \centering\printdiagrams\chessboard[#2]\par
   \small\bfseries #1\strut
    \end{minipage}\hfill\ignorespaces }
\newcommand\introductionboard[2][]{%
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.59\textwidth}
  \raggedleft\printdiagrams\chessboard[#2]\par
   \small\bfseries #1\strut\par\par
    \end{minipage}\hfill\ignorespaces }

\makeatletter
\newcounter{answers}
\extrarowheight3pt
\newlength\colwidth
\renewcommand*\makegametitle{\par\bigskip\newgame  
\refstepcounter{answers}%
\settowidth\colwidth{\fontsize{8mm}{1cm}\bfseries \theanswers}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-\colwidth-3\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}@{}}
\hline
&
\strut$\Box$\quad\textbf{\wname}\ \@welo\hfill\\
\raisebox{0\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\fontsize{8mm}{1cm}\bfseries \theanswers}
&\strut$\blacksquare$\quad\textbf{\bname}\ \@belo\hfill\\
&\strut\quad\@tourn\hfill\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\par\nopagebreak\bigskip\nopagebreak}

\begin{document}
\section*{a Deflection and overloading}


\introductionboard{setfen=8/8/2P2k2/B2Kb3/5p2/8/8/8 w}
1. Bc3! Bc3 2. c7\WBetter


\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\introductionboard{setfen=8/6p1/8/3n3P/N1pk2KP/P7/8/8 b}\\
1...Nb6! 2. Nxb6 c3\BBetter
\end{minipage}

\newpage
\section*{Positions}

\end{document}
```

P.S Added the picture: I don't want to have White to move as text, because I show it with signs. I need just align the diagram and text with /introductionboard

[image]

Comment: sorry I can't see what alignment you want.

Comment: Have edited the post, showing the example of what I want

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot, my answer for instruction board is:

```
\newcommand\introductionboard[2][]{%
 \centering\par\printdiagrams\chessboard[#2]\\}
```